# Calculating the stddev and avg between the most recent number and all the other numbers in a running list snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
id     committed      delivered        timestamp     stddev
1             10              8       01-02-2022          ?
2             20             15       01-14-2022          ?                    
3             12             12       01-30-2022          ?
4              2              0       02-14-2022          ?
.
.
99                                                     null
```

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation between sprint x and all the sprints after sprint x; for example, the standard deviation and avg between sprint `1, 2, 3 & 4`, `2, 3 & 4`, `3 & 4`, and so on. If there are no records after 4, that `stddev` would be null

With the current snowflake functions, I am generally unable to calculate the `stddev` in general, let alone do something with a `lag`/`lead` function.

Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I've figured out how to calculate a moving avg over sprint x and the next sprint, but not for all previous sprints:
`(delivered + lead(delivered) over (partition by id order by timestamp asc)) / 2`

`stddev` can also be calculated using `abs` / `sqrt (2)`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [frame clause](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#label-window-frames) -- this is part of the window function that can specify which rows in the current partition to use in the calculation.

```sql
select
    id,
    stddev(delivered) over (
        order by id asc
        rows between current row and unbounded following
    ) as stddev,
    avg(delivered) over (
        order by id asc
        rows between current row and unbounded following
    ) as avg

from my_data
```

Answer (score 0):

tconbeer is 100% correct, but here is the code and count to "show it working"
and you example data (moshed) into a VALUES section to avoid making a table.

I also stripped out timestamp, as it's not used in this demo, but normally I would order by that, but I could not see the pattern, so just dropped it, as it's non material to the example.

```
SELECT t.*
    ,count(delivered) over ( order by id asc rows between current row and unbounded following ) as _count
    ,stddev(delivered) over ( order by id asc rows between current row and unbounded following ) as stddev
    ,avg(delivered) over ( order by id asc rows between current row and unbounded following ) as avg
FROM VALUES
    (1, 10,  8),  
    (2, 20, 15),              
    (3, 12, 12), 
    (4,  2,  0),
    (5,  2,  0),
    (6,  0,  0)
    t(id, committed, delivered)
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

| ID | COMMITTED | DELIVERED | _COUNT | STDDEV | AVG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 8 | 6 | 6.765106577 | 5.833 |
| 2 | 20 | 15 | 5 | 7.469939759 | 5.4 |
| 3 | 12 | 12 | 4 | 6 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 | null | 0 |

Answer (score -1):

you can create a dummy table which will have a id generated sequentially using the generator function for a particular range and do a LEFT join with the table. This way you will get rows with NULL values where the id is not present, and then you can use lag / leap to get the average.

--- untested

```
select seq4()  as id1 , TMP.* from table(generator(rowcount => 10)) v 
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT * FROM (  
 SELECT   1 as id    , 8 As committed  ,  '01-02-2022' as   delivered    UNION ALL
  SELECT   2 as id    , 20 As committed  ,  '01-14-2022' as   delivered   UNION ALL
  SELECT   3 as id    , 12 As committed  ,  '01-30-2022' as   delivered   UNION ALL
  SELECT   5 as id    , 2 As committed  ,  '02-14-2022' as   delivered  
 )) TMP
 ON trim(id1) = trim(tmp.id)
```

Comment: looking for something much cleaner and if i have a ton of data (my example was a very small sample), this would be time consuming and costly. would definitely work with a very small table though!